# Como puedo hacer para tener imagenes con diferentes anchos dentro de flex, y que este se adapte al contenido de cada una?

Tags: html, css

Estoy desarrollando una web para una empresa, y en la pagina principal, cuenta con 4 imágenes que redireccionan a secciones diferentes.
El problema es que estas imágenes tienen establecido un width de 15em, entonces todas se adaptan a esta medida y quedan de diferentes tamaños...
Como puedo hacer que el contenedor principal flex, se adapte al ancho de cada una y queden todas con la misma proporción?
Es de mucha ayuda cualquier tipo de información, desde ya muchas gracias!

HTML

```
<section id="icon-boxes" class="icon-boxes">
  
        <a href="aceitera.html"><div class="icon-box" id="icon-box">
          <div class="icon-box-image">
          <img src="assets/img/aceitera.png">
        </div>
      </div></a>

        <a href="ganaderia.html"><div class="icon-box" id="icon-box">
          <div class="icon-box-image">
          <img src="assets/img/ganaderia.png"> 
        </div>
      </div></a>
      
      <a href="ganaderia.html"><div class="icon-box" id="icon-box">
          <div class="icon-box-image">
          <img src="assets/img/agricultura.png">
        </div>  
        </div></a>
    
        <a href="arrendamientos.html"><div class="icon-box" id="icon-box">
          <div class="icon-box-image">
          <img src="assets/img/arrendamientos.png">
        </div>  
        </div></a>
  </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#icon-boxes {
  padding-bottom: 0
}

#icon-boxes .icon-box {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

#icon-box:hover {
transform: translateY(-20px);
}

#icon-box img {
  width: 15em;
}

#icon-box, .icon-box-image {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-boxes {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icon-boxes .icon-box {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deberia quedar algo parecido a eso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, podrías adjuntarnos también tu CSS?

Comment: CSS agregado, desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda cris! Espero poder solucionarlo juntos!

Comment: Sucede que las imagenes no tienen la misma altura. Prueba con `height: max-content` o `height: 100%` a tus imágenes. Aunque te recomendaría que las imágenes tengan la misma altura para evitar estos problemas.

Comment: Las imágenes tienen la misma altura,  pero no son de igual ancho, lo qué pasa, es que flex, al dividir en 4 partes iguales me “encoje” la imagen más ancha. Si tenes en mente alguna otra solución, es bienvenida

Answer (score 0):

Una simple solución es poner el contenedor de la imágen a una altura fija: por ejemplo 100px.

Luego las imágenes deben ser de un ancho libre con `max-width: 100%`, y `height: 100%`.

Si la altura del contenedor (`icon-box-image`) es fijo, por ejemplo **100px**, entonces al darle un `height: 100%` a las imágenes ya sería suficiente obtener lo deseado.

```css
            
*,:before,:after {
box-sizing: border-box
} html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0
} a {
text-decoration: none
} #icon-boxes { padding-bottom: 0 } #icon-boxes .icon-box { padding: 0; margin: 0px 15px; } #icon-box:hover { transform: translateY(-20px); } 

#icon-box, .icon-box-image {
display: inline-block;
height: 100px;
}

.icon-box-image {
position: relative;
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 100%
}

.icon-box-image img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.icon-boxes { padding-top: 20px; position: relative; z-index: 100; } .icon-boxes .icon-box { padding: 20px 50px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; border-radius: 10px; }
```

```html
<section id="icon-boxes" class="icon-boxes"> 
        
        <a href="aceitera.html">
            
            <div class="icon-box" id="icon-box"> 
                
                <div class="icon-box-image"> 
                    
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/200/people"> 
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </a> 
        
        <a href="ganaderia.html">
            
            <div class="icon-box" id="icon-box"> 
                
                <div class="icon-box-image"> 
                    
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/200/animals"> 
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </a> 
        
        <a href="ganaderia.html">
            
            <div class="icon-box" id="icon-box"> 
                
                <div class="icon-box-image"> 
                    
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/200/arch"> 
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </a> 
        
        <a href="arrendamientos.html">
            
            <div class="icon-box" id="icon-box"> 
                
                <div class="icon-box-image"> 
                    
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/200/nature"> 
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </a>
    </div> 
</section>
```